# How to list categories by page id in wordpress

Tags: php, menus, widgets, sidebar, categories

I want to create a sidebar with below hierarchy.

- All courses,
- padi courses (these are pages)
- ---divetravel (these are categories)
- ---suba courses (these are categories)

Can someone help me out because I could not able find any solution yet. I found get_category function but it will take post id as parameter. But I want to display categories related to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any programming for something as simple as this. On the menu page, create a menu with these links. Then on the widget page, use the menu widget that comes with WP to add it to your sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I think it will help. I am adding it to answer. Can you help me how to call sidebar in page template, because I am very new to wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a personal tutorial site. There's plenty of help if you google for "tutorial wordpress sidebar"

Comment: Ok no problem I will find it out. Again thanks a lot for the suggestion.